# How to group and return empty results, even if not matching documents were found?

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 queries:

```
aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: {"user_id": 5918725, "shop_id": 1775207, "$text": {"$search" : "API"}}
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: "_id", 
          count: { 
              $sum: { 
                  $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$deleted_at", null ] }, 1, 0 ]  
              } 
          } 
      } 
  }
]);
```

and

```
aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: {"user_id": 5918725, "shop_id": 1775207, "$text": {"$search" : "APIU"}}
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: "_id", 
          count: { 
              $sum: { 
                  $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$deleted_at", null ] }, 1, 0 ]  
              } 
          } 
      } 
  }
]);
```

they are the same, only difference is a search keyword, but they behave differently,
in case of the first query, result is :

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "count" : 0.0
}
```

which is expected result, but in case of the second one, result is `Fetched 0 record(s)` (that is what my GUI shows). So for some reason in case of the second query it simply ignore group/sum and trying to get actual records. How can I solve it, thank you in advance!

Comment: this is expected behaviour, if nothing passes the match, you will just get nothing, if you want to always get  a document with count 0, a simple solution is to use your driver, for example if empty result make this document on your driver. Also grouping by `_id` doesnt make sense, `_id` is unique anyways

Comment: I see, so I can simply treat empty result as 0

Comment: i think its the simplest way, but check the group by `_id` also i dont think this is what you need.Because each id is unique, so group doesnt do anything.

Comment: well, in general I do not need to group at all, I need to get total count, so I can use `_id: null` ???

Comment: yes to make all collection as one group you do  `_id : constant`   and the most used constant used is `null` like no group,  so yes  `_id : null` you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- the easy way to do it its on the driver, if no results you make this document with code
- this is the way to do it on the database, with 2 extra stages, union and group, and one extra collection (in mongodb 5.3 we wouldnt need the extra collection)
- put for example instead of 5 a negative number and even if no results you still get `count : 0`

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=71382160-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match":{"$expr":{"$lt":["$a", 5]}}},
 {"$group":{"_id":null, "count":{"$sum":1}}},
 {"$unionWith":{"coll":"2"}},
 {"$group":{"_id":null, "count":{"$sum":"$count"}}}])
```