# Mongo group with condition not working correctly with full text search

Tags: mongodb

I have another issue related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71382160/mongo-group-by-sum-not-working-in-same-cases/71383095#71383095)

This query

```
aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: {
          "user_id": 1, 
          "shop_id": 1, 
          "$text": {"$search" : "API"}
      }
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: null, 
          count: { 
              $sum: { 
                  $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$deleted_at", null ] }, 1, 0 ]  
              } 
          } 
      } 
  }
])
```

is not working as expected, it is returning 0 as a count value, but should be almost 6k.

But this query (without search)

```
aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: {
          "user_id": 1, 
          "shop_id": 1
      }
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: null, 
          count: { 
              $sum: { 
                  $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$deleted_at", null ] }, 1, 0 ]  
              } 
          } 
      } 
  }
])
```

is working as expected, and also query with search but without `$cond`

```
aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: {
          "user_id": 1, 
          "shop_id": 1, 
          "$text": {"$search" : "API"},
          "deleted_at" : {"$eq" : null}
      }
  },
  { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
])
```

is working as expected, but it's 10 times slower...

Why is the query with search and cond not working?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

okay, I found a solution, it works as expected if I replace `$eq` into `$gt`, but I do not understand why... why this query

```
aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: {
          "user_id": 1, 
          "shop_id": 1
      }
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: null, 
          count: { 
              $sum: { 
                  $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$deleted_at", null ] }, 1, 0 ]  
              } 
          } 
      } 
  }
])
```

with `$eq`, but after adding  `"$text": {"$search" : "API"}` it's not working with `$eq` but working with `$gt`. So the main issue is solved, but now I have more questions than before... :)